# How to diagnose a possibly failed crystal?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, troubleshooting

I'm trying to repair a Panasonic SA-PMX70 audio system and I have narrowed the issue down to a DAC/DSP IC ("BU9447", proprietary, undocumented) which does not seem to be responding at all. It looks like its Pierce clock oscillator does not oscillate. Probing the corresponding IC pins or crystal leads with my scope shows both sitting at roughly Vdd/2 with just 20-30 mV of ripple at the desired clock frequency (24.576 MHz).

The ripple on one pin is shifted by 180° and amplified with respect to the other pin, so I think the amplifier in the IC is working correctly. So I suspect that something is wrong with the crystal. It's a 24.576 MHz crystal in a 3.2x2.5 mm SMD package, labeled "T245 MaCN" (or MoCN?).

How can I confirm that the crystal is indeed toast and replace it? I can easily buy a different crystal with the same package and frequency, but I have absolutely zero idea what the current load capacitance is. I don't have any way to measure C1 and C2, given their tiny size and likely capacitances of 10 pF or so.

Do I just slap a random replacement crystal in and hope for the best? Or is that unlikely to work? (I could try replacing C1/C2 with something that would make the new crystal happy, but I don't know what the parasitic capacitances of the board and the IC are, and I probably can't afford to try several options as the repeated soldering would likely ruin the board.)

I don't know if my measurements are reliable, since I did them with a bog standard 10:1 probe with an input capacitance of 15 pF. I guess it could be affecting the oscillator so much that it stops working. However, measuring a different (16 MHz) crystal on the same board this way works perfectly fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcWCXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The amplitude is indeed very low, so it is suspicious because it is low but also because it still oscillates. So it may be the crystal, or the Pierce inverter circuit inside the chip - but if can also be just a problem of your measurement setup. Please double-check that the probes and scope are capable of measuring 24.576 MHz and make sure the oscilloscope is not set to 20 MHz bandwidth limit mode. Probes must be set to 10x mode. You can also try to feed in logic level square wave from an oscillator module of the same frequency - but it may be risky if you don't know supported voltage levels.

Comment: Find a known-good 24-ish MHz crystal and swap it in - quick and dirty test.  Probably won't work in the grand scheme of things but quick way to determine if oscillation failure is the crystal.  Note it does have to be a crystal for a crystal swap, not a crystal for an oscillator module.

Comment: @Justme The probes have a bandwidth of 60 MHz (in the 10x mode), so I don't expect to see sharp edges at all, just mostly a sine wave of the expected frequency. I did try injecting a square wave test signal to see if it gets through, and it did, but that was at a low (audio) frequency. I don't have a signal generator capable of RF frequencies.